# Continuity equation for the stress-energy tensor in the FLRW metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm trying to compute the continuity equation for the stress-energy tensor $\nabla^\mu T_{\mu\nu}$ in the FLRW metric $$ds^2=-dt^2+a^2(t)ds^2_3$$ where $ds^2_3=g^3_{ij}dx^idx^j$ is the metric for the 3 dimensional space without time dependence. The Christoffel symbols are
$$
\Gamma^i_{jk}=\Gamma^{i3}_{jk}, \space\space\space \Gamma^i_{j0}=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\delta^i_j,\space\space\space \Gamma^0_{jk}=a\dot{a}g^3_{ij}
$$
and the stress-energy tensor components are
$$
T_{00}=\rho, \space\space\space T_{ij}=pa^2g^3_{ij}
$$
My calculation for the $\nu=0$ case is as follows:
$$0=\nabla^\mu T_{\mu0}=\partial_0T_{00}-\Gamma^0_{ii}T_{00}-\Gamma^i_{i0}T_{ii}=\\
=\dot{\rho}-g^3_{ii}\dot{a}a(\rho+p)
$$
While the result is
$$
\dot{\rho}+3\frac{\dot{a}}{a}(\rho+p)=0
$$
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 2 mistakes instead of $\partial_0$ it should be $\partial^0=-\partial_0$ and $g^3_{ii}=3$ since it's the trace of $3$-metric

Comment: thanks for the answer but this doesn't solve the $\frac{1}{a^2}$ difference

Comment: Try doing doing the calculation as $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu 0}$, it is much easier to avoid mistakes this way. If you  raise the index on the covariant derivative, then you need to include factors of the inverse metric when expanding the covariant derivative in terms of Christoffel symbols to compensate for the raised index. I suspect you are just missing these factors.